# accept returns existing connection, causing seg fault

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I am creating a server daemon in c that accepts numerous simultaneous connections, and the clients will be sending data to the server.  I currently have each client connection being spawned into a new thread.  I am seeing that `accept()` will sometimes (not always) return the ID of existing connection which (obviously) causes a wide variety of issues, including segmentation faults.

I even turned off the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` to make sure that wasn't the case.  Whenever a single client makes numerous consecutive calls, everything is fine (`conid` in my code below increments - 5,6,7,8,9, etc...).  But whenever more than one client ties to simultaneously connect, sometimes `conid` gets duplicated (an example from one run: 5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10,10,11,12,12, ...).

I'm wondering how `accept()` can return an existing connection?? It would make sense if I was calling `accept()` within more than one thread, but as you can see below it only exists in the main process thread.  On the other hand, I never experienced this issue with `select()`, so maybe it is an issue with threading???  At this point, I've tried just about everything I can think of, but it's apparent to me I'm just missing something

**Edit:** edited code to show that mystruct wasn't being free'd in the while loop, and (hopefully) provide more insight.

**Edit #2:** per request, I have posted the full source of my example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>


//this is my test structure
struct mystruct_ {
    int id; //only id for testing
};
typedef struct mystruct_ mystruct;

//error logging function
void merr(const char *msg, ...) {
    //get the time
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    //grab this function's arguments
    va_list args;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    va_start(args,msg);
    //build the message
    vsprintf(buf,msg,args);
    //output the message
    printf(" ERROR :: %s\n",buf);
    //that's it!
    va_end(args);
}


//this function handles the threads
void *ThreadedFunction(void *arg) {
    //get the passed structure
    mystruct *test = (mystruct *)arg;
    //print conid -- this is where I am seeing the duplicates
    printf("my connection id is %d\n",test->id);
    // do some stuff, like: pull vars out of mystruct
    int nbytes;
    char buf[256];
    while(1) {
        if((nbytes=recv(test->id, buf, sizeof buf, 0)) <= 0) {
            //handle break in connection
            close(test->id);
        } else {
            //for this example, just print out data from client to make my point
            buf[nbytes] = 0;
            printf("%s",buf);
        }
    }
}

//main just sets up the connections and creates threads
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *port = "1234";

    //get ready for connection
    struct sockaddr_storage addr;
    socklen_t addrsize = sizeof addr;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *ai, *p;
    int sockfd, conid, rv;
    int yes = 1;
    //
    //load up address structs with getaddrinfo():
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me
    if((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &ai))!= 0) {
        merr("failed to bind port '%s': %s\n",port,gai_strerror(rv));
        exit(1);
    }
    //
    //bind the port
    for(p=ai; p!=NULL; p=p->ai_next) {
        sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if(sockfd<0) continue;
        //setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)); //commented for testing
        if(bind(sockfd,p->ai_addr,p->ai_addrlen)<0) { close(sockfd); continue; }
        break;
    }
    //if we don't have p, it means server didn't get bound
    if(p==NULL) { merr("failed to bind port '%s' (reason unknown)",port); exit(2); }
    freeaddrinfo(ai); //all done with this
    //
    // listen to the (now bounded) socket:
    if(listen(sockfd,10)==-1) { merr("listen; errmsg: \"%s\"",strerror(errno)); exit(3); }


    // bind(), listen(), etc... blah blah blah

    mystruct test[1024]; //just for testing
    printf("Ready and Listening...\n");
    while(1) {
        conid = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrsize);//get a connection
        test[conid].id = conid;
        pthread_t p;
        pthread_create(&p,NULL,ThreadedFunction,&test[conid]); //create new thread
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to check is did you bind() correctly?

Comment: yes, I double-checked. `bind()` occurs correctly.  If it does not, I exit the program before accepting connections

Comment: Please post the real code, what you have there is incorrect, specifically `test` is a pointer yet you use `test.conid`. Or at least boil it down to the minimum _compilable and runnable_ program which exhibits the problem.

Comment: okay; my full source is way, waaaaay too big to post, but I've minimized it into a separate example.  This code compiled and ran on my server (Ubuntu 10.04), and I am experiencing the connection issue on this code....

Comment: connection id's I'm getting (for example): 4,5,6,6,7,9,9,10,10,10,12,14,15,16 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is broken:

```
while(1) {
    conid = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrsize);//get a connection
    test[conid].id = conid;
    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p,NULL,ThreadedFunction,&test[conid]); //create new thread
}
```

`pthread_t p;` declares an opaque handle on the stack which `pthread_create` will fill in.  That handle's lifetime must last until you call `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach`.

In this case, the storage for that `pthread_t` is probably being reused, messing up the passing of the argument to the thread function.  At least, that is my guess.

Try calling `pthread_detach` after `pthread_create`.

Comment: Sonds good, unless an overloaded pthread_create() is copying the reference before creating the thread.

Answer (score 1):

`accept` returns a file descriptor that my be reused. As your `ThreadedFunction` never terminates when done with a file descriptor you will get a race condition. So after the `close` statement put `return;`